# remote client intermitency with wcf service hosted in iis

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

I have developed a WCF service and hosted in IIS, I need that this service can be consumed by web applications and for one desktop application, but this desktop application was made in `.net 2.0`, so i add an asmx extension in order to can add the web reference to the desktop app. When I run the app in the same machine that is hosting the WCF service, it works fine, so I installed the system in one client for beta testing. When the client run in the server all requests made to the web services works fine, but this client has 2 remote stations, which have to consume as well the WCF service, now this is the issue, some times the request is not arriving to the WCF, I already added exceptions to the antivirus and firewall, so there is nothing blocking the communication between the server and the client stations.

I'm wondering if all the problem is because an incompatibility issue between the asmx extension and WCF service, but I don't find any after hours googling.

I appreciate any advice about this, the client is a beta, but is pressing hard to get a solucion ASAP.

Comment: enable the wcf tracelogs on both ends